# Omniture tracking in iPhone

Tags: iphone, adobe-analytics

I want to implement Omniture tracking in an iPhone application. I just have a basic clue on Omniture, that it is third party software that helps you to track keyword searches by your users in your application, and it also helps to present similar searches to the users, and helps reporting.  Please correct me if I am wrong as I still digging information on it.

I want to implement the same iPhone form in my application.

I have googled for the information about Omniture tracking, it is scare and there is no help as to how to implement it in an iPhone application.

Can any one guide me how it is done and how to do it iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give much advice if you're building a native Objective C app, other than to say you should read [Omniture's iPhone implementation guide](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/pdf/en/App_Measurement_for_iPhone_Implementation_Guide.pdf). If you're building an embedded web application, and given that you want to integrate keyword search suggestions, I don't think you have much of a choice, but I'd recommend using their regular JavaScript library the same way you would if you were integrating Omniture into your web site. The js engine on the iPhone is fast enough that you probably won't notice any degradation in performance and the memory footprint's not that big.

Comment: I'm sorry no one else could help. Sometimes there's just not enough people to cover a subject here. By the way, are you building a native app or a hybrid (HTML) one?

Comment: a native app, wanted suggested search functionality, etc

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only want to use Omniture because it's the one you've heard of. There are other tracking solutions like Flurry and Google Analytics that both offer iOS SDKs and are easier to implement and easier to find documentation about than Omniture.

I recommend Flurry personally as it gives you more device-specific data that Google does.

http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/ios.html